# RestTemplate equivalent for struts2

Tags: struts2, struts

In spring mvc there's is a class called RestTemplate that you can use to send rest requests in your server side code. See link 
http://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate

Does anything like this exist for struts2 where I can call a restful web service and parse the json response ? Can I do this using the struts2json plugin?

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem? Do you want to use it in struts2?

Comment: I want to call a restful web service in my struts server side code. The restful web service is from an external application. Using any struts libraries if they exist would be the best way to go. P.s. I have the struts json plugin in my Libs and am using it to return json from my action classes. But to my knowledge I don't think I can use that plugin to call a web service from my server side code

Comment: I've been doing some research on this and it looks like to call a restful web service server side and then parse the result I will use the java.net classes and then parse the json using the gson libraries. I don't think struts has n e libraries to help me with this task